# How can I disable CTRL+Z backgrounding in vim or nano?

Tags: linux, bash, bashrc, job-control, stty

I'm using `stty susp ^-` in a user's `.bashrc` shell in an attempt at preventing users from using CTRL+Z to background a process.

The reason behind this, is that we have a number of users who are used to using Oracle SQLPlus on VMS, and the default editor uses CTRL+Z to save and quit the editor. CTRL+Z on Linux obviously has a completely different action, and manages to completely baffle our users as they instinctively hit CTRL+Z.

Whilst `stty susp ^-` seems to work with some commands (e.g. top), it doesn't work when I really need it to, i.e. in editors such as `nano` or `vim`.

Can anyone suggest how I might achieve this?

**Edit**: I don't need to use `bash`, so an alternative shell that doesn't support job control  should suffice (assuming such a shell exists).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable suspend (Ctrl+Z) functionality in `nano`, you can put `unset suspend` into the system global nanorc, which is most likely located at `/etc/nanorc`. See the nanorc(5) man page for details.

Comment: Glad I could help. Also note that this can probably be overriden on a per-user basis; for those brave souls who want to live dangerously, you may want to leave a little note hanging around somewhere. (I haven't tried that scenario.)